# How to rename a collection in mongodb if another collection with same name exists

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, rename

I want to rename a newly created collection using pymongo and the issue is: there is another collection with same name is there.
I am using this command
`db["dept_list_new"].rename("dept_list")`
but it is throwing an error: ""target namespace exists""

Can anyone help me with that??

Comment: So what your plan for the the other collection? The one that already exists with the same name?

Comment: I wanna replace that collection with this new one

Answer (score 0):

Drop the destination collection then rename.

Comment: Doing this only. Kinda looks risky